# display content file in Text widget tkinter with update

Tags: python, tkinter

I try to made Text widgte in tkinter (python 3.6) that display the content of the text file.the problem for me is to have update of the Text widget automatically each 01 second.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter.ttk import Notebook
import time

root=Tk()
root.geometry('540x420')
root.title('Text update')

ILS=ttk.Notebook(root,width=520,height=450)

releves_loc35R = Frame(ILS,bg="powder blue")
ILS.add(releves_loc35R, text = 'releves')

data_loc35R = Frame(ILS,bg="powder blue")
ILS.add(data_loc35R, text = 'data')

ent_mon=StringVar()

#pour stocker les valeurs des mesures du LOC 35R
def archiver():

    mes_archives={
                  "jour" : time.strftime('%d/%m/%y  à  %H:%M:%S', time.localtime()),                
                  "lecture_monitor": ent_mon.get(),                               
                  } 
    textInsert=("\n"+str(mes_archives["jour"])+"\n"+"\nddm lue avant la correction au Monitor 1 :"+str(mes_archives["lecture_monitor"])+"\n\n=======================================\n")

    mon_fichier=open("archives/file.txt", "r")
    #ouverture du fichier texte (data_loc35R)
    text=mon_fichier.read()
    mon_fichier.close()

    fileW = open("archives/file.txt", "w")
    fileW.write(textInsert+text)
    fileW.close()

canvas=Canvas(releves_loc35R)
canvas.place(x=4,y=70)
monitor = LabelFrame(canvas, text="Lecture Monitor 1",padx=5, pady=5,font=('arial',12,'bold'))
monitor.pack(padx=6, pady=6)

entry_monitor = Entry(monitor,font=('arial',10,'bold'),textvariable=ent_mon)
entry_monitor.pack(pady=5)

#bouton d'archivage de la correction
bt_archiver=Button(releves_loc35R,text='Archiver',command=archiver)
bt_archiver.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=SW)

##########################
def affichage_update():
    with open("archives/file.txt","r") as f:
        data = f.read()
        s = Scrollbar(data_loc35R)
        T = Text(data_loc35R)
        s.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        T.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        s.config(command=T.yview)
        T.config(bg='powder blue',font=('arial',14,'bold'),pady=14, yscrollcommand=s.set)
        T.insert(END,data)
    T.after(1000,affichage_update)

affichage_update()

ILS.pack(expand=1, fill='both', padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

when I introduce information via the entry interface of the labelframe. they are not displayed at the same time in Text widget, but are stored in the text file
i don't knew why the update fuction that I created      is not worked
I want help to resolve this problem

Comment: I have rectified the code and it has actually worked now. unfortunately, when I introduce this little script in the total code of my application, I have the same problem as before

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `Text()` widget every time `affichage_update()` runs, and for some reason the first one stays on top.

Instead create only one `Text()` widget and change the contents in the function:

```
# Building the data tab text widget
s = Scrollbar(data_loc35R)
T = Text(data_loc35R)
s.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
T.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
s.config(command=T.yview)
T.config(bg='powder blue', font=('arial',14,'bold'),
         pady=14, yscrollcommand=s.set)

##########################
def affichage_update():
    with open("file.txt","r") as f:
        data = f.read()
        T.delete('1.0', END)  # Remove previous content 
        T.insert(END,data)    # Insert text from file
    T.after(1000,affichage_update)
```